# Installing Remote Zoom-In on non-dev PC

Tags: windows-mobile

When developing for Windows Mobile I use "Remote Zoom-In" to take screen shots of the mobile device. This is part of Visual Studio 2008. I want to install this on a document-writer's PC but I don't want to install Visual Studio. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install Remote Zoom without installing Studio (you might be able to copy it, but the connectivity pieces will be a challenge), but you can install [SOTI Pocket Controller](http://www.soti.net/PCPro/), which is free to try.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I ended up using this: http://mymobiler.com/?p=72. I probably should have done a bit more research before posting a question. - Cheers Mark